# How did Stack Overflow get people to start asking questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-history

Stack Overflow has 10 million questions, many of which rank #1 for their respective keywords in Google. But it was not always so...

What specific things did Stack Overflow do to reach a critical mass where people were using the site regularly?

For example, Stack Overflow was announced with [blog posts](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) and podcasts. What was the impact of these announcements? What other major things were done to attract, retain, and engage users?

Comment: Interesting question :) How does any site garner the first registration and usages, be it a forum or a Q&A site where you need both sides of the coin; those asking the questions and those answering them. I'm guessing it boils down to having a network already when you set it up that you can invite to be the first participants.

Comment: @Gimby You're probably right about Atwood's popularity playing a sizable part. I expect the gamification of the site helped too.

Comment: Both [Jeff](http://blog.codinghorror.com/) and [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) already had sizable audiences from their own individual blogs.

Comment: That however does not answer the actual question I realize by thinking about it for more than 2 seconds - what did SO *do* such that it not only lifted off, but continued to attract people to it - especially the fact that people like to invest considerable amounts of their personal time in helping to keep the machine chugging is something quite unique to stack as a tech site. Be a darned well-designed site, for starters I'd say.

Comment: I won't be surprised if they pulled of a The Facebook-esque move and import expertsexchange questions. ;)

Comment: It was the time i almost got used to google's `Not from site: experts-exchange` predicate in extended search when i found a solution at SO.

Comment: @CodeCaster: [They didn't even import the Joel Data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991)! See [10k: "Where, oh where, did the Joel Data go?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go)

Comment: This did not happen over-night.  The first fat year, SO was not very good at generating useful Q+A.   Lots of water-cooler chat, career-advice and jokes, lots of it has been deleted.  Just take a glance at what survived, note that (almost) everybody that contributed back then has disappeared and never came back.  Turn-around was ~Nov 2009, meta was the strongest influence in getting rid of the subjective stuff afaik.  Lots of subject experts became active, liking the focus and format, the site got Google love and took off.

Comment: Similar to what Google did with Gmail, SO ran a not-very-seeekrit kewl-kidz-only beta program, so people were enticed to participate in part by the feeling of exclusivity and "hey, you're one of the in-crowd".

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy that site had a lot to do with my initially learning to write my own adblock rules.  It's Google hit were actually usable(ish) after you blocked the 300 or so screens of filler in the middle of the page trying to make you think you had to pay to see the answer instead of just setting a marble on your pgdn key and going to get a coffee while it scrolled.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs here too: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I always figured it got started [something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkxRzV3gtDc)

Comment: They just had to request Jon Skeet to join. Then everything else happened!

Comment: Ah, I see the Skeet jokes are starting to come in...#Skeet4Prez2016.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has come along and snarkily asked how Stack Overflow got people to *stop* asking questions yet.

Comment: @Bob: Thank you. To this day it never occurred to me that JoS and Coding Horror were two *different* blogs. And yes, I know that Sposlky and Atwood are two different people.

Comment: @Cupcake Because clearly they never figured that one out.

Comment: it's not less interesting how subject matter experts started participating by answering questions

Answer (score 42):

According to Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood (sorry, I don't remember the exact sources), by the time Stack Overflow was launched they were both reputed bloggers with quite a few followers. So just posting the announcement of the site launch in their blogs caused a significant amount of people to start using it, thus gaining the required momentum to continue growing. I for one learned about it in [Jeff's blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/) (and I even remember voting for the site name in [a blog post that contained a poll](http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website)).

Comment: There was also the weekly podcast (promoted through now defunc *IT Conversions* starting from episode eight), started about four months prior, on 2008-04-16 (19 episodes before the *public* launch of Stack Overflow).

Comment: [The name poll](http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/)

Comment: @stuartd - I'm really glad that fello whackers was a joke. It's almost as bad as the pre-hyphenated expert-sexchange.

Comment: @spender Yikes! Sure enough. I should visit [English StackExchange](http://english.stackexchange.com) more often. :-)

Comment: It's basically like Exploding Kittens - the creators had big enough fan-bases to provide a ready-made community. JoelOnSoftware was a big deal (I'm sad it's basically over these days)

Comment: "quite a few followers" = 1 million as far as I remember what Joel said on the podcast once.

Comment: @theB No, it isn't nearly that bad... Bad, but not as bad as that.